# Export E-Training Reports Automatically

Tags: csv, web, export, moodle

We have an E-Training Site for work. The system administrator needs to print out the results for each course. What he does now is clicks on each individual course, and then clicks on the export to csv option. However, he has 100 or more courses. Is there a way to automatically get the reports into csv format without him having to click on each course? Right now it's taking him about an hour and a half just to get the csv reports. The E-Training runs on Moodle, if that helps.

Comment: Could you add which version of Moodle it is and also which report it is, maybe just add the url for the report

Comment: Thanks for the response, the version is:


 Moodle 2.8.1+ (Build: 20141211)  


I'll check what url the user is going to...